# want to Install ubuntu 14.04 in my windows 8 pc and want to remove windows without losing any previous partition and data

Tags: partitioning, windows

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC and remove Windows 8 without losing any previous partitions or data. I have booted my pendrive for installing Ubuntu 14.04 but I do not know how to install Ubuntu 14.04, remove Windows 8, and preserve all my data using the installer options.

Comment: The only safe way with 14.04 is with Something Else. And I would suggest dual booting until you are used to Ubuntu. You still need a Windows repair flash drive as periodically you will need to run chkdsk on your NTFS data partition. Better to eventually convert to Linux format, but you have to backup and restore. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI AND: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: So there is no way what i want, am i right ???

Comment: The option you probably want is "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" or "Something else". I would first install Ubuntu alongside windows, copy all the data you care about off the Windows partition (from inside Ubuntu), delete the entire Windows partition, and finally expand the Ubuntu partition if you want. It might also be a good idea to create a separate "Data" partition that has no OS and only your data to make similar operations easier in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will do it,

1.Make some free space/unallocated space ( about 50 GB ) by shrinking or deleting volume from current partitions ( using windows ).

2.boot ubuntu installation media.

3.now in the "installation type" select "something else".

4.add 3 partition -

i. select type > primary, allocate size > 20GB as ext3/4, mount point > /

ii. select type > logical, allocate size > 26GB as ext3/4, mount point > /home

iii. last of all 4GB as swap

That's all set for installation.

If you want to remove your windows partition just format/delete it after installing ubuntu ( after removing your needed files ).

**NTFS file system can be mounted in linux using [ntfs-3g](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G) & can be used natively.**

Then run update-grub as root ( sudo update-grub ).

**note: You can set your desired partition size according to your need or can expand it later.**